# MySQL Beginner Join Query

Tags: mysql, join

Schema: tblCusotmers stores customers, tblAddresses stores their addresses, each customer has many addresses;

tblCustomers
customer_id: 1
name: XYZ Corp

tblAddresses
address_id: 1
customer_id: 1

address_id: 2
customer_id: 1

address_id: 3
customer_id: 1

I want to, given an address ID, retrieve all address IDs of the addresses belonging to the same customer. So given the above example, given address ID 3, I want the numbers 1, 2, and 3 returned.

I'm sure this is a simple join but I've been trying and trying to work it out in my head and can't. Can someone put me to shame please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAddresses 
WHERE customer_id = (SELECT customer_id FROM tblAddresses WHERE address_id=3)
```

This uses a subquery to get the customer_id for the correct row and uses it in the where clause. [MySQL Docs on subqueries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subqueries.html)

With a JOIN (a little bit more complicated, but as you specifically asked):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tblAddresses AS t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT customer_id FROM tblAddress WHERE address_id=3) AS t2
ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
```

Answer (score 3):

JOINs are the tool for the job.  Generally speaking, subqueries should only be used to do things that can not be done with JOINs.

This should be the optimal way to get what you want (make sure there is an index on tblAddresses.customer_id):

```
SELECT t2.id
FROM tblAddresses AS t1
JOIN tblAddresses AS t2 ON t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id
WHERE t1.address_id = 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although correct subqueris was something new to me and helped me with the next section of my project otherwise it  would have meant another question so thank you also :D